# Refresh only one div with AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to dynamically reload only one div in my page every five seconds. But in my response I get the content of the whole page... How can I get only the content of the specified div ?

```
<script>
function ajaxrefresh()
{
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            //Here i want only the content for the div from the response       
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        else
        {
            //alert("state: "+xmlhttp.readyState)
            //alert("status: "+xmlhttp.status)
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://${localHostAddress}:8080/adress",true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    var t=setTimeout(ajaxrefresh,5000);
}

window.load = ajaxrefresh();
</script>
```

Comment: Provided the data is not personal or secret, like a bank balance, creating software on the server that sends back only the info you want may be preferable to adding more and more code to the browser side.  Bind this software to a different URL.  Then you can use ajax to request only that piece of data from that specific URL.  Advantages: less of an ugly hack, less wasted network usage, better scalability

Answer (score 1):

Someone has already ask something like this on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447928/ajax-response-as-dom-object). Best voted-up is to create an invisible div in your page, and fill it with the AJAX response to be able to get back element you need with `hiddenDiv.getElementById("myDiv")`.

Answer (score 1):

As you can not use Jquery, I think your best bet is in response to ajax call return only the div contents from server side. this way your response size will be smaller and hence faster too...

if you can not change the response of request use below code

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
  //Here i want only the content for the div from the response  
  var mydiv= document.getElementById("myDiv"); 
  var doc=document.createElement("div");
  doc.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  document.body.appendChild(doc); // Note append temp to document
 mydiv.innerHTML=doc.getElementById("theDivYouWant")
    .innerHTML;
  document.body.removeChild(doc);// Note remove temp from document
```

Comment: This could cause strange behavior if the xml request is made to the currently opened page, appending the page again might cause double Element id's and getElementById might not return what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
  //Here i want only the content for the div from the response  
  var doc=document.createElement("div");
  doc.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=doc.getElementsByTagName("div")[5]
    .innerHTML
```

Here 5 is just a random number, if the div is always fixed you can use the number that the div is located and if it's not you need to loop through the divs and find the one you're looking for (maybe based on id).

Comment: I can't call doc.getElementById...
TypeError: doc.getElementById is not a function

Comment: Yes, if you use the first option then you can only use getElementsByTagName and such, not getElementById but the second one should return a document object so you can use getElementById.

Comment: I see, haven't used a bare xmlhttpobject for a long time. It seems that it sometimes returns a document object if you set the responseType but that isn't implemented in some browsers. So you have to set innerHTML of a div and get the element with getElementsByTagName, then loop through them and get the element you want (maybe based on the element's id?)

Comment: If you realy want to have a document object and have to use getElementById then you can use a DOMParser to parse the text into a document but some browsers (read IE) don't support parsing html text so you have to add that feature with some JS code. The code and how to to it can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Answer (score 0):

May be you will get some idea from below script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
       var auto_div_refresh = setInterval(function(){
   $('#load_data').load('fb_count.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
```